# Is the word "thing" necessary in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, superlatives

Example:

> I couldn't find any information about lemmings. Seemed like it wasn't a very popular topic. The closest (**thing**) I could find was a news article about them.

Comment: Your specific word ***thing*** is simply an alternative to [optionally] repeating the previously-specified noun  ***information** [about lemmings].*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Closest* there can stand on its own as a substantive. *Thing* is not needed. Both versions are idiomatic.

Comment: "substantive"? You mean our own "nominal"? I thought substantive was old-fashioned English.

Comment: The new grammarians are very protective of their jargon :-)

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, "thing" isn't necessary. Because of the context, it should be obvious what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

**The closest** stands for **the closest information**.

Instead of repeating the word, information, we use the superlatives as pronouns in place of the closest information.